# nvcc warns about a device variable being a host variable - why?

Tags: cuda, compiler-warnings, nvcc, compiler-bug, template-variables

I've been reading in the CUDA Programming Guide about template functions and is something like this working?

```
#include <cstdio>

/* host struct */
template <typename T>
struct Test {
    T  *val;
    int size;
};

/* struct device */
template <typename T>
__device__ Test<T> *d_test;

/* test function */
template <typename T>
T __device__ testfunc() {
    return *d_test<T>->val;
}

/* test kernel */
__global__ void kernel() {
    printf("funcout = %g \n", testfunc<float>());
}
```

I get the correct result but a warning:

"warning: a host variable "d_test [with T=T]" cannot be directly read in a device function" ?

Has the struct in the testfunction to be instantiated with `*d_test<float>->val` ?

KR,
Iggi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the CUDA compiler seems to generally have some issues with variable templates. If you [look at the assembly](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:cuda,source:'%0A/*+host+struct+*/%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+Test+%7B%0A++++T++*val%3B%0A++++int+size%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A/*+struct+device+*/%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0A__device__+Test%3CT%3E+*d_test%3B%0A%0A/*+test+function+*/%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0AT+__device__+testfunc()+%7B%0A++++return+*d_test%3CT%3E-%3Eval%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A/*+test+kernel+*/%0A__global__+void+kernel()+%7B%0A++++printf(%22funcout+%3D+%25g+%5Cn%22,+testfunc%3Cfloat%3E())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'CUDA+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:nvcc92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'1',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:cuda,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'NVCC+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+CUDA',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:68.64784546805349,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+NVCC+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:31.352154531946507,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), you'll see that everything works just fine. The compiler clearly does instantiate the variable template and allocates a corresponding device object.

```
.global .align 8 .u64 _Z6d_testIfE;
```

The generated code uses this object just like it's supposed to

```
ld.global.u64   %rd3, [_Z6d_testIfE];
```

I'd consider this warning a compiler bug. Note that I cannot reproduce the issue with CUDA 10 here, so this issue has most likely been fixed by now. Consider updating your compiler…

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue on CUDA 10.1 with Fedora 29, using `-std=c++14`, so I think it may still be present.  Thanks to those who filed bugs.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm using CentOS 7.6, CUDA 10.1 and the gcc (g++) 8.2.1 compiler from the devtoolset-8 with -std=c++14.

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelKenzel is correct.

This is almost certainly an nvcc bug - which I have now [filed](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia_bug/2546472) (you might need an account to access that.

Also note I've been able to reproduce the issue with less code:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo { int  val; };

template <typename T>
__device__ foo<T> *x;

template <typename T>
int __device__ f() { return x<T>->val; }

__global__ void kernel() { int y = f<float>(); }
```

and have a look at the [result on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/UnWrxz) as well.